# How to write controller to create a resource and a nested resource from one form in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a `recipe` object and multiple nested `ingredient` objects from one form in Rails 5.  As it stands, I am able to create `recipe` objects, but am given errors when passing `params` to create an `ingredient` object, specifically `NoMethodError`:

```
undefined method `ingredient' for #<Ingredient id: nil, ing: "s", amount: "s", recipe_id: nil>
```

This is my form:

```
<%= form_for(@recipe, url: recipes_new_path) do |f| %>
<h1>
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %><br>
</h1>
<h1>
    <%= f.label :steps %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :steps %><br>
</h1>
<%= f.fields_for :ingredient do |p| %>
    <h1>
        <%= p.label :ing %><br>
        <%= p.text_area :ing %><br>
    </h1>
    <h1>
        <%= p.label :amount %><br>
        <%= p.text_area :amount %><br>
    </h1>
<% end %>
<%= f.submit "Add" %><br>
```

Included in routes.rb:

```
....
resources :recipes do
    resources :ingredients
end
```

Included in models:

```
class Ingredient < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :recipe
  ....
end

class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :ingredients, dependent: :destroy
    ....
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients, allow_destroy: true
    validates_associated :ingredients
end
```

Controller for `recipe`:

```
....
def new
    @recipe = Recipe.new
    @ingredient = @recipe.ingredients.build
end

def create
    @recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)
    @recipe.save
    @ingredient = @recipe.ingredients.build(recipe_params[:ingredients_attributes])
    if @ingredient.save
        redirect_to recipe_path(@recipe)
    else
        render 'recipes/new'
    end
end
....
def recipe_params
    params.require(:recipe).permit(:name, :steps, ingredients_attributes: [:ing, :amount])
end
```

From what I can tell, I'm either incorrectly passing `params` to create an `ingredient` object, or I shouldn't be trying to create an `ingredient` object in the `recipe` controller at all.

**EDIT**

Change in form from

```
<%= f.fields_for :ingredient do |p| %>
```

to

```
<%= f.fields_for :ingredients do |p| %>
```

**EDIT**

Full error:

```
Started POST "/recipes" for ::1 at 2016-12-14 09:19:43 -0600
Processing by RecipesController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"RfBXiL7vFla2/SvLqR2WrgzsfFMOqVRpjTavmvrPMJ/YBhF7UR+CeGV5NNRNyQfuALuJXc9hafPre+wPOo6n2A==", 
"recipe"=>{"name"=>"a", "steps"=>"a", "ingredients_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"ing"=>"a", "amount"=>"a"}}}, 
"commit"=>"Add"}
    (0.1ms)  begin transaction
    (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 37ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
NoMethodError (undefined method `ingredient' for #<Ingredient id: nil, ing: "a", amount: "a", recipe_id: nil>
Did you mean?  increment):  
app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb:14:in `create'
Rendering /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout
Rendering /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
Rendered /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (5.6ms)
Rendering /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
Rendered /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.8ms)
Rendering /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
Rendered /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (2.5ms)
Rendered /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (154.0ms)
Rendering /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb
Rendered /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.7ms)
Rendering /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript
Rendering /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string
Rendered /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (1.5ms)
Rendering /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string
Rendered /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.9ms)
Rendering /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string
Rendered /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.6ms)
Rendered /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (148.7ms)
Rendering /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript
Rendered /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.6ms)
Rendered /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (284.4ms)
```

Comment: I was just wondering, why are you passing `recipies_new_path` into your form? If it comes from elsewhere, so you define that path within the link.

Comment: Earlier in development, it was a shortcut to fix a problem.  I've since updated it to `form_for @recipe ... `

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to change your `fields_for` to use "ingredients" plural:

```
<%= f.fields_for :ingredient do |p| %>
```

This is because your recipe `has_many :ingredients`. If your recipe only `has_one :ingredient` then your form would work as written.

UPDATE: You should also change your `create` method as follows:

```
def create
  @recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)
  if @recipe.save
      redirect_to recipe_path(@recipe)
  else
      render 'recipes/new'
  end
end
```

Because you are passing `ingredients_params` through the `recipe` params, you don't need to create the ingredients separately - they will be automatically created by `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in your Recipe mode.

For a timeless tutorial on nested forms, see Ryan Bates' [Nested Model Form](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised) on Railscasts.

Comment: Made this change, which changed `ingredient` to `ingredients_attributes` in `params`, but still facing the same problem.

Comment: It may be caused by setting and saving the ingredient separately in the create method. You shouldn't need to do this - try applying the change that I just mentioned in the updated answer.

Comment: Made the change, but had no affect :-/ should I have anything in the `ingredient` controller corresponding to `recipe` create action?

Comment: Are you still getting the same error, or a different one?

Comment: Can you post the complete output from your logger for that request?

Comment: Started POST "/recipes"
Processing by RecipesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"RfBXiL7vFla2/SvLqR2WrgzsfFMOqVRpjTavmvrPMJ/YBhF7UR+CeGV5NNRNyQfuALuJXc9hafPre+wPOo6n2A==", "recipe"=>{"name"=>"a", "steps"=>"a", "ingredients_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"ing"=>"a", "amount"=>"a"}}}, "commit"=>"Add"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 37ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
NoMethodError (undefined method `ingredient' for #<Ingredient id: nil, ing: "a", amount: "a", recipe_id: nil>

Comment: See original post for something more wieldy

Comment: Maybe 'ingredient` is being called somewhere else, like in your model. The answer is probably in the stacktrace, which would be right after the request log that you posted. It should tell you the file and line number where the exception occurred.